# OpenLayers setCenter will not function properly

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am using OpenLayers for a map and when I load it, it always centres on 0,0 no matter what I change the setCenter to.

```
    var map, baseLayer;
    var options = {numZoomLevels: 7, isBaseLayer: true,};
    function collegeLaneInit()
    {

        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');            
        baseLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Image("College Lane","college-lane-large.png", 
        new OpenLayers.Bounds(-1000, -1000, 1000, 1000),
        new OpenLayers.Size(2000,2000), options);
        map.addLayer(baseLayer);

        var center = new OpenLayers.LonLat(500,500);
        map.setCenter(center ,1);  

        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
        map.zoomToMaxExtent();
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());

    }
```

I'm not really sure why it's doing this. Can anyone spot something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
map.zoomToMaxExtent();
```

Is your offending line, comment it out, if you zoom out far enough you will always end up in the centre

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me! However now it is zoomed in too much! Is there a way to have it be at zoom level 1 as default?

Comment: No worries, I figured it out! Thanks a bunch! :D

Comment: @mrpopo could you share what you found?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide valid Latitude and Longitude values (Lon in [-180:180]; Lat in [-90:90]), since default projection in openlayers is `EPSG:4326` ([reference](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.projection)). 
<strike>Furthermore you need a [baselayer](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.baseLayer) in order to make it work, or load your image from a mapserver.</strike> (you set is as a baselayer). Is your image georeferenced?